# Google Maps stops sending map tiles and reverts to 0, 0 lat lng

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an Android app that gets it's location every 3 seconds and displays it on a google map. After a while, the map stops updating, and reverts to 0,0 lat lng in it's display. The rest of my app shows I am still getting new lat lng values back, but the map won't update and remains at 0,0. I think this has to do with some sort of quota for how many map images my app can request in a 24 hour period. If I wait until the next day, it works again. If I don't and instead reinstall the app and get a new registration id, it works again. Does anybody know anything about this possible limitation and how to remove it even if it involves payment? I read about the 25,000 images limitation, but I don't think I'm generating 25,000 from just one app riding around in a car for a half hour. And even if it were that, it would only generate a warning from them, not the stoppage of new map images. So there must be some other limitation going on that I can't find out about. Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: I dont think the android maps API has an "image limitation" certain google maps api's such as static map images do have this limit however

Comment: Well, I am using Google Maps Android API v2. The app doesn't bomb, and the lat lng textview where I display the lat and lng keeps updating. The mapping doesn't bomb or go blank. It just reverts to it's default location and zoom and remains there. Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: Well, you can check how many quota you used on your Google developer console. If it works next day, you may overlimited the quota